# Error in Compiling OpenCV Sample Programs with CUDA

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04 on jetsonTX1 with CUDA8.0, and I have a trouble with compiling opencv sample code in opencv/samples/gpu.

I could compile sample in opencv/samples/cpp, such as

```
g++ -ggdb facedetect.cpp -o facedetect `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

worked, but not in samples in gpu folder.

### First try

I tried following command,

```
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` optical_flow.cpp -o optical_flow
```

I got this error:

```
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `drawOpticalFlow(cv::Mat_<float> const&, cv::Mat_<float> const&, cv::Mat&, float)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1162: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `drawOpticalFlow(cv::Mat_<float> const&, cv::Mat_<float> const&, cv::Mat&, float)':
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:92: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::setTo(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `showFlow(char const*, cv::cuda::GpuMat const&)':
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:128: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::GpuMat::defaultAllocator()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `showFlow(char const*, cv::cuda::GpuMat const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp:453: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::Stream::Null()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `showFlow(char const*, cv::cuda::GpuMat const&)':
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:129: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::split(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::cuda::GpuMat*, cv::cuda::Stream&)'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:137: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:155: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:156: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:175: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::GpuMat::defaultAllocator()'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:176: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::GpuMat::defaultAllocator()'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:178: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::GpuMat::defaultAllocator()'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:180: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::BroxOpticalFlow::create(double, double, double, int, int, int)'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:181: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::DensePyrLKOpticalFlow::create(cv::Size_<int>, int, int, bool)'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:182: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::FarnebackOpticalFlow::create(int, double, bool, int, int, int, double, int)'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:183: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::OpticalFlowDual_TVL1::create(double, double, double, int, int, double, int, double, double, bool)'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:186: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::GpuMat::defaultAllocator()'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:187: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::GpuMat::defaultAllocator()'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:192: undefined reference to `cv::getTickCount()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `main':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:80: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::Stream::Null()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:196: undefined reference to `cv::getTickCount()'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:196: undefined reference to `cv::getTickFrequency()'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:203: undefined reference to `cv::getTickCount()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `main':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:80: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::Stream::Null()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:207: undefined reference to `cv::getTickCount()'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:207: undefined reference to `cv::getTickFrequency()'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:214: undefined reference to `cv::getTickCount()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `main':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:80: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::Stream::Null()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:218: undefined reference to `cv::getTickCount()'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:218: undefined reference to `cv::getTickFrequency()'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:225: undefined reference to `cv::getTickCount()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `main':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:80: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::Stream::Null()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:229: undefined reference to `cv::getTickCount()'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:229: undefined reference to `cv::getTickFrequency()'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:235: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:236: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/home/ubuntu/opencv/samples/gpu/optical_flow.cpp:237: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:622: undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:664: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:592: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:613: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `cv::Mat::create(int, int, int)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:684: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int)'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:704: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `cv::String::String(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.inl.hpp:81: undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `cv::cuda::GpuMat::GpuMat(cv::Size_<int>, int, cv::cuda::GpuMat::Allocator*)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda.inl.hpp:75: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::GpuMat::create(int, int, int)'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `cv::cuda::GpuMat::GpuMat(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::cuda::GpuMat::Allocator*)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda.inl.hpp:112: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::GpuMat::upload(cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `cv::cuda::GpuMat::~GpuMat()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda.inl.hpp:118: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::GpuMat::release()'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `cv::cuda::GpuMat::convertTo(cv::_OutputArray const&, int, double, double) const':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda.inl.hpp:188: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::Stream::Null()'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda.inl.hpp:188: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::GpuMat::convertTo(cv::_OutputArray const&, int, double, double, cv::cuda::Stream&) const'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `cv::Mat::Mat(cv::cuda::GpuMat const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda.inl.hpp:624: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::GpuMat::download(cv::_OutputArray const&) const'
/tmp/cc6S867H.o: In function `cv::Mat_<float>::operator=(cv::Mat const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:1481: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::reshape(int, int, int const*) const'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:1484: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::convertTo(cv::_OutputArray const&, int, double, double) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I test this sample code to confirm my installation?

At least, python2.7 can import cv2 and some function such as 'imread' works fine.

### Second try

Then I tried

```
  g++ -L/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ optical_flow.cpp -o optical_flow `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -lopencv_gpu
```

But it comes to

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_gpu
```

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

### Additional Information

My build information from cv2.getBuildInformation() is :

```
General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0 =====================================
  Version control:               3.1.0-3-g50b7dfd-dirty

  Platform:
    Host:                        Linux 3.10.96-tegra aarch64
    CMake:                       3.5.1
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               Release

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.4.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):
    Linker flags (Debug):
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so gtk-3 gdk-3 pangocairo-1.0 pango-1.0 atk-1.0 cairo-gobject cairo gdk_pixbuf-2.0 gio-2.0 gobject-2.0 gthread-2.0 glib-2.0 v4l1 v4l2 avcodec-ffmpeg avformat-ffmpeg avutil-ffmpeg swscale-ffmpeg /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libsz.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so correspondence multiview numeric glog gflags dl m pthread rt tbb atomic cudart nppc nppi npps cufft -L/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 cudev core cudaarithm flann hdf imgproc ml reg surface_matching video cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping dnn fuzzy imgcodecs photo shape videoio cudacodec highgui objdetect plot ts xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo datasets rgbd stereo structured_light superres tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow sfm stitching python2
    Disabled:                    world contrib_world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python3 viz cvv matlab

  GUI: 
    QT:                          NO
    GTK+ 3.x:                    YES (ver 3.18.9)
    GThread :                    YES (ver 2.48.2)
    GtkGlExt:                    NO
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
    WEBP:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x0202)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.54)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.6)
    JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     NO
    GDAL:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      codec:                     YES (ver 56.60.100)
      format:                    YES (ver 56.40.101)
      util:                      YES (ver 54.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
      resample:                  NO
      gentoo-style:              YES
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    UniCap:                      NO
    UniCap ucil:                 NO
    V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.10.0) / libv4l2 (ver 1.10.0)
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Xine:                        NO
    gPhoto2:                     NO

  Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 4.4 interface 9002)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     NO
    Use VA:                      NO
    Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
    Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.92)
    Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 8.0)
    Use OpenCL:                  NO
    Use custom HAL:              NO

  NVIDIA CUDA
    Use CUFFT:                   YES
    Use CUBLAS:                  NO
    USE NVCUVID:                 NO
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             53
    NVIDIA PTX archs:
    Use fast math:               NO

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
    numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.0)
    packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled

  Documentation:
    Doxygen:                     NO
    PlantUML:                    NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              NO

  Install path:                  /usr

  cvconfig.h is in:              /home/ubuntu/opencv/build
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

### My paths

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then get

```
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/usr/local/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, somehow I could solve this problem after recompiling opencv.

```
cmake .. -DWITH_OPENGL:BOOL=ON -DWITH_QT:BOOL=ON -DWITH_CUDA:BOOL=ON -DCUDA_ARCH_BIN="5.2" -DCUDA_ARCH_PTX="5.2" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebugInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG:BOOL=OFF -DENABLE_NEON:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=ON -DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES:BOOL=ON -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules
```

After all, my build information become like this.

```
General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0 

=====================================
  Version control:               3.1.0-3-g50b7dfd-dirty

  Platform:
    Host:                        Linux 3.10.96-tegra aarch64
    CMake:                       3.5.1
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               RelWithDebugInfo

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.4.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):
    Linker flags (Debug):
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent Qt5::OpenGL /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so v4l1 v4l2 avcodec-ffmpeg avformat-ffmpeg avutil-ffmpeg swscale-ffmpeg /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libsz.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so correspondence multiview numeric glog gflags dl m pthread rt /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so tbb atomic cudart nppc nppi npps cufft -L/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 cudev core cudaarithm flann hdf imgproc ml reg surface_matching video cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping dnn fuzzy imgcodecs photo shape videoio cudacodec highgui objdetect plot ts xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cvv datasets rgbd stereo structured_light superres tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow sfm stitching python2
    Disabled:                    world contrib_world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python3 viz matlab

  GUI: 
    QT 5.x:                      YES (ver 5.5.1)
    QT OpenGL support:           YES (Qt5::OpenGL 5.5.1)
    OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so)
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
    WEBP:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x0202)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.54)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.6)
    JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     NO
    GDAL:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      codec:                     YES (ver 56.60.100)
      format:                    YES (ver 56.40.101)
      util:                      YES (ver 54.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
      resample:                  NO
      gentoo-style:              YES
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    UniCap:                      NO
    UniCap ucil:                 NO
    V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.10.0) / libv4l2 (ver 1.10.0)
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Xine:                        NO
    gPhoto2:                     NO

  Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 4.4 interface 9002)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     NO
    Use VA:                      NO
    Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
    Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.92)
    Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 8.0)
    Use OpenCL:                  NO
    Use custom HAL:              NO

  NVIDIA CUDA
    Use CUFFT:                   YES
    Use CUBLAS:                  NO
    USE NVCUVID:                 NO
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             52
    NVIDIA PTX archs:            52
    Use fast math:               NO

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
    numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.0)
    packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled

  Documentation:
    Doxygen:                     NO
    PlantUML:                    NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       NO
    Performance tests:           NO
    C/C++ Examples:              YES

  Install path:                  /usr/local

  cvconfig.h is in:              /home/ubuntu/opencv/build
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```